# How do I generate a PayPal Request Payment and send an invoice?

Tags: ruby, paypal

I am writing a stand alone Ruby script to generate an invoice as a PDF file. Everything is working well so far.

I'd like to know how do I connect to my PayPal account in this script and send a "Request Payment" to the purchaser?

Currently, after I generate the PDF invoice offline with my Ruby script, I need to log onto PayPal manually, and click on the "Request Money" tab in PayPal, type in the recipient's email address, enter the amount, etc. and click "Request".

I want to see if there is a way to automate the PayPal request money part.

This is a stand alone Ruby script, not Ruby on Rails or a web application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mechanize is a good gem for mimicking user actions on websites. You can use this to script any action you would otherwise perform as a user and get the results you need in your script.

Comment: Thank you very much for quick help. I think I prefer a PayPal sort of API that I can program in a NON-GUI environment.

Comment: There are many rack solutions you can use for that too. There's a rack app that basically defines the single user payment (can't recall really if this is what PayPal calls it).

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can use the PayPal Invoicing API's for this.
These will let you create, send, create-and-send invoices on the fly.
In order to use the Invoicing API you'll need to register an application via www.x.com and get an 'Application ID'.
You can find more information on the Invoicing API at https://www.x.com/developers/paypal/products/invoicing -- the developer guide is available at https://cms.paypal.com/cms_content/US/en_US/files/developer/PP_InvoicingAPIGuide.pdf